# Is there a free video converter that allows you to adjust color settings (filters) like brightness, contrast, and gamma?

Tags: windows, gratis, video, media-converter, color

Is there a free video converter that allows you to adjust color settings (filters) like brightness, contrast, and gamma?

I read [Free, lightweight, all-in-one, audio and video format converter](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/70/is-there-a-free-lightweight-all-in-one-audio-and-video-format-converter) (well, I asked it), but from the list of answers, I know that Handbrake, Freemake, WinFF (though this says nothing about ffmpeg itself), and Format Factory don't support filters.

I'm looking for free (gratis), non-command-line software for Windows.

Answer (score 4):

I can't believe that in the other question no one mentioned [**Avidemux**](http://avidemux.org).

- free / open-source
- cross-platform
- graphical interface
- filters for hue, contrast, brightness, color and many others (from Video menu - Filters)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[FFMPEG](https://ffmpeg.org) is fast and free plus has 100's of video & audio [filters](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html). Of these the [eq](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#eq) filter allows brightness, contrast, saturation and approximate gamma adjustment.

It is a good idea to have a read of the FFMPEG documentation and test your command on a short section of your movie so that you don't spend too long finding the settings that work for you. *I have seen reports that the filters will only apply while re-coding so you may need to convert to another format first if you wish to stay in the existing format.*

An example command line, from this [blog](https://wjwoodrow.wordpress.com/2015/07/12/more-ffmpeg-hell/), is one to correct for florescent lighting:

```
ffmpeg -i all.m2ts  -vf eq=1:0:1.3:1:1:0.9:1:1 -c:v libx264 -c:a libfaac temp0.mp4
```