# Free program to make a slideshow of pictures

Tags: windows, gratis, video, images

I have a folder of pictures, and I want to make a slideshow out of them (ie. a video with images changing every few seconds with different transitions and if possible, music)

Please recommend a free program with the following features:

- runs on Windows 10
- takes a folder/group of photos as an input
- makes a slideshow of them, automatically
- with different transitions for each one (they can be repeated, of course!)
- lets me add music in the background
- is free
- exports to common video formats (eg. .mov, .mp4, .avi, etc...)

Comment: The order of the images does not matter? How often shall they repeated max? What are the input file formats (images and music)? Do all images have the same format (width*height)? What is the expected output format (in pixels)?

Comment: Your request sound much like a command line utility. Do you need a fully automated solution or is manual interaction ok?

Comment: @ThomasWeller no matter in which order. The pictures shouldn't be repeated, but the transitions can be repeated every 7/8 or more pictures. Inputs will be .png or .jpg, audio .mp3. Not all same format, best output possible. It could be a command line utility, but it should be automated (so it can be without GUI, but I should simply be able to choose a bunch of pictures and settings)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## **[Bolide Slideshow Creator](http://slideshow-creator.com/)**

- Runs on Windows
- You can just drop as many photos to the timeline
- Add transition effects automatically (either the random or selected ones)
- Save your slideshow as a video file(**AVI, MKV, FLV, MP4 or WMV**)
- Output video file resolution can be from 128x160 to 1920x1080 pixels (**FullHD**)
- Completely free
- Support of almost any image format
- Support of **MP3/AAC/WMA/M4A/MP4/OGG** music files for the background audio

I guess that fits all your requirements. Hope this helps. Cheers!!!

Comment: Sorry for the delay, but this works perfectly! Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend [Slideshow Maker](http://icecreamapps.com/Slideshow-Maker/) by Icecream Apps.

It will take a folder of images as an input. To use all of the images you have in a folder go into the folder select one image and then press Crtl+A. This will select all of the images which you can then use to create your slideshow. You can then choose from a bunch of different transitions. You can add audio by choosing a .mp4 file or another audio format as your background music.

The only downside to this piece of software is that it only exports to .mkv files. So you will need a converter to convert the .mkv files to a popular format.

Another downside to the slideshow maker is that in Windows 10 it will not reformat to the screen size well when you drag it up to the top or to the side. You have to click the full screen button to make it full screen. This is a minor annoyance but an annoyance none of the less.

Comment: Thanks, and sorry for the delay in getting back to you! It matches my requirements perfectly, but I liked another answer a bit better :)

Answer (score 1):

## [Windows Movie Maker](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/movie-maker)

[image: wmv]

This often comes installed with Windows but it seems it was removed in Windows 10. It's neither elegant not particularly powerful but should meet most of your requirements.

- It's compatible with Windows 10
- You can select all the photos in a folder as input media for a video
- The [AutoMovie](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-sg/windows-vista/make-a-movie-quickly-in-windows-movie-maker-automovie) functionality allows you to quickly generate a themed (or unthemed) movie with the photos and music you select
- Transitions are present and can be applied individually to each photo
- Music can be added
- Gratis
- Only exports to `wmv`. [Older versions including 2.1](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-SG/windows/get-movie-maker-download) export to `avi` as well but this functionality has since been removed. You can always [convert](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/70/is-there-a-free-lightweight-all-in-one-audio-and-video-format-converter) the video though.

Comment: My previous experiences with Windows Movie Maker had been bad, it always crashed whenever I did something. However I tried using it again and it worked so thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

## [PowerPoint](https://products.office.com/en/powerpoint) (>= 2007)

Microsoft Office PowerPoint fits your requirements because it allows you to create photo slideshows and export them in common video formats. In Microsoft-speak, this is known as a [*PowerPoint Photo Album*](https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/Create-and-share-a-photo-album-6febdf8b-5179-4e63-90a6-0fb68df97ec6).

> 1. On the Insert tab, in the Images group, click the arrow under Photo Album, and then click New Photo Album.
> 2. In the Photo Album dialog box, under Insert picture from, click File/Disk.
> 3. In the Insert New Pictures dialog box, locate the folder that contains the picture that you want to insert, and then click Insert.
> 4. If you want to change the order in which the pictures are displayed, under Pictures in album, click the file name of the picture that you want to move, and then use the arrow buttons to move it up or down in the list.
> 5. In the Photo Album dialog box, click Create.

PowerPoint certainly isn't free, but its ubiquity especially in the business world means there's a very good chance you already have it installed. The video created can then be exported in various formats including `mp4` and `wmv`.

Comment: Sorry for the delay! Been busy testing. I actually didn't know about this, so thanks for teaching me something! +1 :)

Answer (score 1):

Get [Picasa](http://picasa.google.com/). It's a Google software.

[You can combine your photos, videos, and music into a movie by:](https://support.google.com/picasa/answer/19539?hl=en)

> 1. Select photos and videos for your movie.
> 2. At the top, click Create Movie Presentation.
> 3. Use the Movie Maker to alter movie settings, adjust audio and transition, dimensions, add and edit text to slides, or add new photos.
> 4. Click Create Movie or YouTube to create the movie and upload it to YouTube.

Movies are saved on your computer in the Movies, folder under `My Pictures` > `Picasa`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion :) It worked for me, but I liked one of the other answers a bit better :)