# Convert multiple .m4a or wav audio files to mp3

Tags: windows, audio, mp3, file-converter

My question is about **converting** multiple audio files from one format to another especially from **.m4a** to **mp3**. Is there any software that can do it? Also I'm interested in converting it using only **Windows software**.

If not multiple, single conversion solutions would also be appreciated. All I want is little or no decrease in quality of sound.

Comment: Have you tried VLC?

Comment: VLC for conversion?

Comment: Correct.  In the *Media* menu, you will find *Convert / Save...* (or just press Ctrl+R)

Comment: Would commercial/paid solutions be acceptable, and if so, what is your price limit?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Free, lightweight, all-in-one, audio and video format converter](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/70/free-lightweight-all-in-one-audio-and-video-format-converter)

Comment: Is a GUI required or can it also be a CLI application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[FFMGPEG](http://ffmpeg.org/) is available for Windows, is able to support variable bit rate and works really well for audio as well as video.

On a single file:

```
ffmpeg -i yourfilename.m4a -codec:v copy -codec:a libmp3lame -q:a 2 yourfilename.mp3
```

For batch conversion, with windows command line extensions:

```
SETLOCAL ENABLEEXTENSIONS
FOR I IN (*.m4a) DO ffmpeg -i %I -codec:v copy -codec:a libmp3lame -q:a 2 %~dpnI.mp3
```

If you wish to specify an output directory rather than putting files where the originals were you can replace `%~dpn.mp3` with `\path\to\ouput\dir\%~n.mp3` where `\path\to\ouput\dir\` must be an existing directory.

Of course you can do a lot more with FFMPEG such as converting video formats, cutting and splicing video, extracting or adding soundtracks.

- Price: Gratis
- Open Source
- Cross Platform *available for Windows, OS-X & Linux*

Answer (score 0):

I use [xrecode](http://xrecode.com/xrecode3/) for those kind of conversion.

The demo version work fine too.